# When to use "ac" instead of "et"?

Tags: syntax, conjunction, semantics, word-usage, case

What's the difference between the conjunctions: *"et"*, and *"ac"*?

Which one corresponds to what kind of situation?

---

Allow me to elaborate for clarification, and to distinguish from similar questions. Consider the following two, similar university slogans and their official interpretations:

**[University of Queensland](https://www.uq.edu.au/)**
*Scientia ac Labore*
"[Through] knowledge and hard work"

**[University of New South Wales](https://www.unsw.edu.au/)**
*Scientia Manu et Mente*
"Knowledge [by] hand and mind"

---

Are they both semantically and syntactically correct?
Are their respective translations accurate?
Assuming the answer to both questions is yes:
Why do they use different forms of the same conjuction?

Comment: Welcome back to the site! I'm afraid your question had been asked before. Could you please see the linked post and tell us if that answers your question? If not, please modify your question adding what doubts you still have.

Comment: This question seems to have been asked before, so I marked it as duplicate. This doesn't mean that there's anything wrong; we just want to have all the answers collected in one place. If the linked question does not satisfy your needs, you can edit your question to elaborate and it can be reopened. This is a good question indeed!

Comment: Thanks for the friendly comments. I've added to the question. Hopefully it's an improvement.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, nothing provides a better brief on the semantics of these conjunctions than a good dictionary. L&S has quite exhaustive (if not exhausting) articles on [*et*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Det) and [*ac/atque*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Datque). You can supplement it with others at hand, for example, the Oxford Latin Dictionary, which is not available online.

In the present narrow context, both conjunctions mean pretty much “and,” but there is important semantic difference. *et* has unmarked conjunctive force, just like English “and,” while *ac* is more marked, in a sense binding the two ideas more tightly together, but at the same time introducing contrast between them. Note the internal form of *at-que* ≈ “and-but.” English clearly does not have such a particle; “but” is even more disjunctive than *at*.

> Are they both semantically and syntactically correct?
>   Are their respective translations accurate?

**Yes** and **yes.**

> Why do they use different forms of the same conju<n>ction?

They are using *different* conjunctions. It is entirely incorrect to think of *ac* and *et* as “forms” of some abstract meaning “and,” realized in the English word “and.” Latin and English are independent languages on their own, and there is no one-to-one semantic relationship between any two languages.

I do not think it is possible to answer this question literally; the choice of words is in the mind of the speaker, and we cannot peek in there. It is nevertheless instructive to examine somewhat different semantics of these two mottos.

> scientia manu et mente

Here “by hand” and “by mind” are simply joined, and English “and” will convey the closest possible meaning: the *manu* and *mente* are, in a sense, nearly equal partners in this conjunction.

> scientiā ac labore

Here the “and” translation is also possible, but the Latin semantics is richer. The subtlety introduced by “hard” in the translation is felt; “work” is now perceived somewhat more heavyweight in this sentence. *ac* has a similar emphatic quality toward the second conjunct. The sentence can be roughly translated “by knowledge and also work,” with the force of almost, but not quite, “by not only knowledge but also work.” Think of ***ac* meaning half “but also,” half “and also”** in this context.

I understand that the explanation is a little hand-wavy, but languages are different in their semantic repertoire, and particles, often being fossilized shards from earlier stages of a language, carry perhaps even more subtleties in their meaning than significant words, due to their relative longevity.